# Asynchronous bitmap buffering with GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, asynchronous, bitmap

I am bulding up a grid of images for an app I'm building. It works like so:

1. Build up a list of Image IDs, which I must query using a different content provider each (these are images from MMS threads)
2. Create new activity, which hosts an `ImageGridFragment`. This fragment has a custom adapter that takes the grid of images, and loads each one as a bitmap asynchronously.
3. After images are loaded, they are cached in an LRU cache so I don't need to run unnecessary computation

So far, everything works quite well. However, I would like to pre-buffer images so that when the user scrolls down, s/he doesn't have to wait for images to load. They should already be loaded. The stock Android Gallery accomplishes. I've had a look at the source, but think there must be a more straightforward way.

**To answer members' questions**

1. Images are loaded one by one using the `content://mms/part/xxx`, where `xxx` is the ID of an image. These are MMS images, and to my knowledge, cannot be loaded as a batch process (though, maybe I'm wrong). I use a content provider in an `AsyncTask` to load each image

**I've tried the following:**

1. Pre buffer 30 images or so right when the fragment is created. This is not ideal because the massive I/O request, actually prevents the on-screen images from loading quickly (but the buffering does work well!)
2. Detect when the requested view to load is at the very bottom-right hand corner of the screen, which could work, but then would fail in the case that the GridView takes up only part of the screen. It also seems like there should be a cleaner way to do this
3. Thought about, but did not try, an `OnScrollListener`, but this will not pre-buffer images until I start scrolling, which is not ideal

**So, my questions are:**

1. Is there a good way to detect when the **last GridView** item is requested to load? I found that the `GridView.getlastvisibleposition()` method is not useful here, because it is actually returning the last element for which `Adapter.getView()` has been called for. If I can do this accurately, I can launch the buffer request at that time
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do right this

   if(GridView.getlastvisibleposition() = mAdapter.count()-1)
2. how you load the images? 
   is it from URL or from sdcard? 
   are you using a image loader library?

Comment: I answered # 2 in the original post. The suggestion will not work. The adapter returns a count based off of how many image ID's I pass to it. Only a small subset of these images are visible at any one time, so the code you suggest evaluates to true only when the last element is showing.